# How to build an Universal app to read and write NFC tags

Tags: c#, windows-phone, nfc, win-universal-app, iot

I have been searching for how can I build an Universal app to read NFC tags and I not found a clear way to start the code.

Some one knows how to read and write an NFC tag by a Windows Phone??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a code sample [nfc-ndef-tag-reader](https://github.com/Microsoft/nfc-ndef-tag-reader) shows how to read the NFC tags on Windows Phone 8.

The function SubscribeForMessage is still available on Universal Windows Platform. So you can still use the code in your Windows Universal App.

Comment: You know how to write on a NFC tag?